# Inconsistent behaviour with native back and toolbar up/back in Android Espresso UI test

Tags: android, kotlin, android-espresso

I'm currently writing UI tests using Espresso, and I'm seeing inconsistent performance with **up back** i.e. the back button in the toolbar and native back.

Native back -> NoActivityResumedException is thrown

```
@Test(expected = NoActivityResumedException::class)
    fun validateNativeBackNavigationClosesActivity() {
        pressBack()
    }
```

Toolbar up back -> NoActivityResumedException is **NOT** thrown

```
@Test(expected = NoActivityResumedException::class)
    fun validateUpBackNavigationClosesActivity() {
        onView(
            CoreMatchers.allOf(
                CoreMatchers.instanceOf(AppCompatImageButton::class.java),
                withParent(withId(R.id.toolbar))
            )
        ).perform(click())
    }
```

Any ideas why the toolbar up back is not performing the same as the native back using espresso? I can confirm that the back logic is working but the exception is not being thrown..

I would expect the toolbar up/back to throw the same exception as native back

```
@Test(expected = NoActivityResumedException::class)
    fun validateUpBackNavigationClosesActivity() {
        onView(
            CoreMatchers.allOf(
                CoreMatchers.instanceOf(AppCompatImageButton::class.java),
                withParent(withId(R.id.toolbar))
            )
        ).perform(click())
    }
```